# how to match html tag

Tags: regex, scala

I have to parse string like this:

```
foo <img ... > <strong>foo</strong> bar
```

and i need to replace img tag with an empty string

```
foo <strong>foo</strong> bar
```

I've tried with

```
<img.*>
```

but the result is

```
foo bar
```

How can i do?

PS: the html string is malformed

Comment: offtopic: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/371804

Comment: if you add a `?` after `.*` then it becomes a lazy match.  For example a greedy match like `<.*>` would get "<abc><def>" from the string "<abc><def>". But `<.*?>` would only get "<abc>".

Comment: @LukStorms Seems work ;-) let me testing it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match the tast of SO this answer will have three parts
* Answer to your problem
* Official rant
* Cleaner soulution

## Answer to the problem

`*` is greedy so it will match to much. Two solutions are possible:

1.) `*?` non greedy match all
2.) `<[^>]+>` all within brackets

## Rant

Never parse HTML using regex. There are many subtele errors you can run into. There is also this post on this: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

## Cleaner soultion

Parse using XML-Parser with TagSoup https://hackage.haskell.org/package/tagsoup.
Here is an example that lets you treat HTML as XML like structure with Scala and tagsoup: https://github.com/daandi/spOCR/blob/master/src/main/scala/biz/neumann.parser/HTMLParser.scala